# How to start verdaccio by pm2?

Tags: pm2, verdaccio

pm2 start verdaccio failed, the status is stopped.

```sh
$ npm i -g pm2 verdaccio

$ pm2 start verdaccio
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've have been running `verdaccio` in pm2 for 1 year by know and I use this after installing it globally via npm.

Start

```
pm2 start `which verdaccio`
```

Restart

```
pm2 restart verdaccio
```

And that works pretty well for me.

Comment: Then the app has crashed, check your logs.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is pm2 finding verdaccio in the first place. That's why using `which` solves it, but that is not always possible in Windows.

I've managed to run verdaccio in pm2 on Windows, without even installing it globally (so that I could commit my configs, plugin packages, etc), with this:

```js
// ecosystem.config.js
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'verdaccio',
    script: './node_modules/verdaccio/build/lib/cli', // local package, that pm2 can run with "node <script>"
    args : '--config ./config.yaml', // local confis
    node_args: '-r esm', // verdaccio's package didn't contain "type": "module"
    exec_mode: 'fork' // verdaccio does not currently support PM2's cluster mode
  }]
}
```

PS.: these are my dependencies:

```json
// package.json
  "dependencies": {
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "verdaccio": "^5.10.2",
    "verdaccio-activedirectory": "^1.0.2",
    "verdaccio-simplegroup": "^1.0.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

for someone still stumbling upon this problem. you can try deleting the process then starting it again. I solved it this way.